# AndroidStudio- Unable to run project because "Cannot resolve Symbol R"

Tags: android

So I am unable to execute the project due to this error. Now, I tried the following techniques that I saw on here:
-Rebuilt and cleaned the project
-Restarted Android Studio
-Created a new project and Readded the files, running the project after every major file was added.

Now, the third problem provided me with some clues. When I added a fragment and put some code in and ran the project, I got the following 2 errors :

Error:(1) Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Temp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

When I opened the gradle console I saw the following:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Temp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I am a beginner programmer so I am not really sure what to make of this.

Any help will be appreciated. I have attached the code from the fragment.xlm below:

```
<?xml verion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
    android:text="" />


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed" means that there is a problem compiling your XML file, such as an incorrect namespace, and extra/stray character, a missing or misplaced closing or opening tag, or other spelling mistake.

In your case there is a spelling error on the first line.

```
<?xml verion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, that was such a stupid mistake, sorry :(

Comment: You're welcome. We've all made errors like that at one point or another, so no worries.